# Navigation Bar Location in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, android-8.0-oreo, android-navigation-bar

How can I know, when the **orientation is landscape**, what **side** of the screen is the the **navigation bar** located?

In many devices and Android version below 7 I see the navigation bar is always located at the right, when the orientation is landscape. But there are phones where the navigation bar is at left, when the screen is rotated 270 degrees.

I've found the same behaviour in these two devices with **Oreo**:
- Google Pixel
- Nexus P6

I have tried, although it didn't work, to do something like:

```
Rect visibleFrame = new Rect();
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(visibleFrame);
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
boolean isRightOfContent = dm.heightPixels == visibleFrame.bottom;
boolean isBelowContent   = dm.widthPixels  == visibleFrame.right;
```

What else should I try?

What I'm trying to do is to detect what side the navigation bar is in fullscreen, with immersive mode, so I apply a left or right margin in order to leave space for a button.